# Do I need separate water heater for each gas/electric unit (for multi-family dwelling)?

Tags: water-heater

I am seeing just one water heater for a multiple family home. I am not sure if the gas used in the water heater is charged for just one gas/electric unit or separately. Can a single water heater be hooked up to 2+ units?

Comment: This is very likely dependent on the country/state/city/etc. local codes. As a general rule, I would think "not a good idea", but certainly on the large scale there are big buildings with many units sharing a single large boiler system. So no simple answer without knowing where you are.

Comment: Where are you on this planet? How many units does this building have, and how are they heated (space heating)?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel NJ, West New York. 2/3 family with 4 baths. Tank with natural gas.

Comment: Is the existing gas service master metered or separately metered, or is this a new gas service installation?  Also, is it two units or three?

Comment: Can be, sure. Can work fine, as well, if properly sized. Whether it's a good idea from a utilities point of view rather depends on who is paying for the gas to feed it - if it's the landlord or condo association and hot water is included in the rent or association fees, works fine. If one tenant or owner is paying for everyone else's hot water, not fine. Which of those applies is not clear from your question.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel separately metered (3) and three units seems

Comment: What other gas appliances do the units have in them?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Three ranges/stoves (including ovens) and boiler + baseboard

Comment: I take it the building water service is separately metered as well?

Answer (score 0):

### I would use *indirect* hot water heaters here

Since the units already have hydronic heat, it makes very little sense to have a whole separate (and likely inefficient) burner for providing domestic hot water service when instead, it can run off the existing boilers, using what is called an *indirect hot water heater*.  These look like, and behave like, typical tank-type hot water heaters, save for the fact that they are not heated by a gas flue/heat exchanger or electric immersion elements, but by a hydronic heat exchanger coil in the tank that has hot water from the boiler passing through it.

This gives you the advantage that you can gain very high efficiency (comparable to a *very* good gas water heater) when you pair an indirect tank with a modern, modulating-condensing type hydronic boiler and good installation practices.  You also get a broader choice of materials for the tank in indirect heaters than you do in just about any other type of heater; instead of the typical glass-lined tanks, you can get tanks made from various grades of stainless steel, or cement-lined steel tanks for that matter.  This can provide a low-maintenance option with no need to worry about anode changes or element burnouts, and longer warranty periods as well, up to limited lifetime warranties in some cases.

Furthermore, indirect tanks can be placed with a fair degree of flexibility, as they do not need access to the flue/vent system in the building, and are available in "low-boy" models as well as a variety of sizes.  Furthermore, the high efficiency of the fully immersed coil-type water-to-water heat exchanger used in an indirect tank allows them to achieve higher *first hour recovery* figures, gallon for gallon, than any other type of water heater on the market. This allows the use of a *much* smaller tank than would otherwise be required with a standard gas heater, provided the underlying boiler can put out the BTUs needed to drive the tank, of course.

This also holds no matter if the building uses a central boiler plant or per-unit boilers; either way, the indirect tanks simply wind up being separate hydronic zones from the baseboards.  Note that you will need three tanks in either case, as using a single tank relies on the building *water* supply being master metered, and that's rare in a small multi-unit building like this.